# Tensorflow Sparse Tensors Issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I was trying to run the following TensorFlow Code. It included sparse matrices but it don't seem to be working. I've modified the example given in tensorflow's documentation ([Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/placeholder)). I'm using tensorflow version 1.12.0.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.sparse.placeholder(shape=[-1,8,8], dtype=np.float32)
x_reshaped = tf.sparse.reshape(x, shape=[-1,64],name='flow_sizes_reshaped')
layer = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random_normal(shape=[64, 32],stddev=.05), name='hidden_layer_0', dtype=np.float32)
x_final = tf.sparse.matmul(x_reshaped, layer)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  indices = np.array([[0, 2, 0], [0, 5, 1]], dtype=np.int64)
  values = np.array([1.0, 2.0], dtype=np.float32)
  shape = np.array([1, 8, 8], dtype=np.int64)

  print(sess.run(x_final, feed_dict={
    x: (indices, values, shape)}))
```

Error:

```
2018-12-11 13:24:39.039224: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_Sparse.py", line 15, in <module>
    x: (indices, values, shape)}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1132, in _run
    raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Const:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int64) may not be fed.
```

I don't think its a dimension mismatch issue because if I make this change in the code:

```
indices = np.array([[2, 0], [5, 1]], dtype=np.int64)
```

I get the following error:

```
2018-12-11 13:30:01.538664: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_Sparse.py", line 15, in <module>
    x: (indices, values, shape)}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1128, in _run
    str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 2) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'
```

I've tried to do multiple things, but I end up getting this issue everytime. I am now thinking of going to the TF source code and checking out why this error is being raised.

Comment: are you sure your dimensions matched up?

Comment: The error changes if the dimensions don't match. So for example if I change the indices to: indices = np.array([[2, 0], [5, 1]], dtype=np.int64) I get ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 2) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'

Comment: It's weird but it happens because of `tf.sparse.reshape`. 
There's a workaround, which is to reshape your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird but it happens because of `tf.sparse.reshape`. 
More precisely, when tensorflow builds the computation graph, it adds all constant tensors as non-feedable, which makes sense. Thus, when you do reshape and pass a sparse tensor `x`, it adds its dense_shape as a constant tensor (I think at this place there must be made a copy of this tensor). Finally, when you run the graph with `sess.run` and passes `x` which consists of 3 tensors including `x.dense_shape`, tensorflow checks that all included tensors can be fed and fails on `x.dense_shape`.

Another option is to make a placeholder for the shape of `x`:

```
x_shape = tf.placeholder(shape=[3], dtype=np.int64)
x = tf.sparse.placeholder(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float32)
...
print(sess.run(x_final, feed_dict={
    x_shape: [-1, 8, 8],
    x: tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)
}))
```

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it and if it works (Reshaping the input data) I'll choose this as the correct answer.

Comment: Thats an amazing solution (placeholder for the shape for x) as my shape may vary as the first dimension is the batch size but I'll look into the source code and flag this as a bug.